# Latex geometry package giving an inconsistent binding offset

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to prepare a thesis which requires 4cm margins on the side where it will be bound (i.e, left hand side on odd numbered pages) with 2cm margins on the opposite side. I have been trying to use the geometry package with these options but get strange results. This code should replicate my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[inner=2cm,outer=2cm,bindingoffset=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\newpage

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

This gives this output:
[image: Image showing incorrect offsets]

As you can see, the offsets are different between the two pages. I have tried forcing the text width to be 15cm which did nothing, and also using the asymmetric option with inner=4cm, outer=2cm.

Is there a way to correct this so that the opposite margins of even and odd pages are the same?

edit:

Using verbose and showframe with lipsum[1-10] as suggested by cfr gives:[image: second attempt]

I think the margins either side of the middle separation should be symmetrical and 2cm on each side.

## EDIT (cfr)

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[inner=2cm,outer=2cm,bindingoffset=2cm,verbose,nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

produces the following output on the console:

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* bindingoffset: 56.9055pt
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(56.9055pt, 426.79137pt, 56.9055pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(101.40665pt, 591.5302pt, 152.11pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=426.79137pt
* \textheight=591.5302pt
* \oddsidemargin=41.54102pt
* \evensidemargin=-15.36449pt
* \topmargin=-0.93083pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=18.06749pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=25.29494pt
* \marginparwidth=0.0pt
* \marginparsep=0.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
```

Note that the left margin, text width and right margin are calculated correctly:

```
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(56.9055pt, 426.79137pt, 56.9055pt)
```

`426+3*57` makes up the total of `597` pts for the paper width. But there is no acknowledgement of the offset which this assumes:

```
* \hoffset=0.0pt
```

I'm not sure whether this should be positive (because the binding offset is positive) or negative (because the binding offset is less than 1in) but surely it ought not be zero? Moreover, the differences observed by the OP of roughly 5mm correspond more-or-less to the difference between 1in and 2cm, which is 4mm. Somehow, the calculations are not taking account of all of the desiderata selected.

But `geometry` always confuses me...?

Comment: Welcome! Please post an example ***which produces the output you've shown***. As it is, your code does not even produce a double-page spread because the first page is on the right and the second on the left. You need at least 3 pages. If I change the first `\lipsum` to print ``1-10` rather than `1-2`, I get 3 pages, but I do not get the problem you show in your screen shot. So I still can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you say `\usepackage{layout}`, then you can get more information by inserting `\layout` into your document. Also add `verbose,showframe` to the options you pass `geometry`.

Comment: Hi cfr, thanks for your fast response. The code posted builds and shows what I screenshotted, however I added the dimensions on afterwards. I have edited the question to include more paragraphs as you suggest and the result of the showframe. The left hand margin on the even page is 2.5cm which I think should be 2cm.

Comment: You are printing it on A4 size paper, right?

Comment: What happens if you set marginparsep=0cm?  As in `\usepackage[inner=2cm,outer=2cm,bindingoffset=2cm,showframe,marginparsep=0cm]{geometry}`

Comment: OK. I see the problem. `geometry` takes no notice of `bindingoffset` at all. I tried to work around it using the `layout` options for setting layout size and offset and that just made things worse.

Comment: @JPi I tried `marginparwidth=0pt, marginparsep=0pt` and, alternatively, `nomarginpar`. That helps reduce the warnings - there are no longer complaints. But it doesn't touch the problem. You can see it in the output on the console. `geometry` acknowledges that you've passed `bindingoffset`. But it makes zero difference to the horizontal division of the page.

Comment: I've edited your question to add some further details. If my edit does not make sense to you or reflect your situation, please simply roll it back.

Comment: @JPi See edit to question.

Comment: As a work around, `inner=4cm, outer=2cm` seems to work fine.

Comment: It works as expected for me. I have on both inner sides 4cm margin (2cm +2cm). `\hoffset` is 0pt as expected too (the boundingoffset is added to the margins). Is your geometry version up-to-date? Did you check with other viewers and/or printers?

Comment: I confirm the Ulrike Fischer's findings: I have no problem. The text width with your top example is 15cm, not 14.5. The `geometry` package never sets `\hoffset` or `\voffset`, that should only be used for fixing small printer driver issues.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for having a look at this; you saying you could not replicate it made me look into my build options more and the issue was the dvips step being run with "-t letter". Thanks for all your time and help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a bad command line option passed to dvips, so nothing to do with geometry and just a user error.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was my quick build settings, while I had put a4paper in my latex document dvips was being run with the -t letter flag.